# Use variable in IN clause

Tags: sql, visual-studio, variables, report

Im new to writing visual studio reports and linking them to stored procedures. Ive picked up the easy bits like 1 variable on the form can equal one variable in the stored procedure, such as a start data or end date.

I have a drop down list of my report where a user can select a company name, they could tick multiple company names.

I have set the company name to equal a variable in my sql but don't know how to get it all to link together as it wont make the values from the drop down into a string.

This is a simplified version of my query

```
Declare @ContactID int
Declare @CompanyName nvarchar(max)



set @CompanyName = @CompanyNameParam
set @ContactID = (select ContactID from Company co inner join Contacts c on c.CompanyID = co.CompanyID where CompanyName = @CompanyName)


select *
from company co inner join contacts c on c.CompanyID = co.CompanyID
where ContactID in (@ContactID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want more than one contact.  If so, use a table variable.  For your sample code:

```
Declare @CompanyName nvarchar(max);
set @CompanyName = @CompanyNameParam;

declare @Contacts table (
    ContactId int
);

insert into @Contacts(ContactId)
    select ContactID
    from Company co inner join
         Contacts c
         on c.CompanyID = co.CompanyID
    where CompanyName = @CompanyName;

select *
from company co inner join contacts c on c.CompanyID = co.CompanyID
where ContactID in (select ContactId from @Contacts);
```

Comment: I get an error "Must declare scalar variable @companyname" when I try to preview the report, I have named the dropdown list on the report as company name where users can tick the names they want to view, have I missed something, I am new to visual studio so don't know if ive just linked something wrong

Comment: Ok ive altered the query so that the @CompanyName looks at the companyname drop down and now just getting a syntax error which I had to start with saying "Incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: I tried adding the @companynameparam in, I think the issue is converting this into a string of values to then pass into the contacts table as if I just set CompanyName = ('Blue,'Red,'Yellow) then i get an error line in my sql code on the comma after the Blue so it cant read the string in by looks of it

Comment: @user3691566 . . . That seems like quite a different problem from the one this question is addressing.

Comment: ok thanks, your code does work for one though so I will see if I can adapt that to allow multiple company names.

Comment: @user3691566 . . . The solution for multiple company names depends entirely on how you represent the names.  There are several different viable approaches.